# Power stroke path effect behaves in the wrong way in Inkscape

Tags: vector, inkscape, path, path-effects

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuhytmNCngg), but it seems that somthing goes wrong since the very beginning. Indeed, starting with this simple path
[image]
when I add the *Power stroke* effect, I unexpectedly obtain the following
[image]
How can I have this effect behaving just the way it is supposed to?

Inkscape version: 0.91

Comment: The settings on your screen don't match what's on the tutorial... Perhaps that is the issue.

Comment: What settings are you referring to?

Comment: start / end cap. Check the answer from Billy Kerr.

Comment: I've played with those settings, but nothing changes (not the way it should).

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis No matter what settings I make I can't replicate the problem. This leads me to suspect a bug in 0.91

Comment: Someone downvoted the question. I'd like to know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate your problem with the most recent Inkscape 0.92.  Perhaps if you were to update to the most recent version it might fix it. It could be a bug which has been fixed.

Example screenshot

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: With version 0.92 everything works fine. It seems that is was a bug in the 0.91 version. (Provided that uninstalling that version hasn't removed strange and unwanted settings causing that behavior.)